# How do I get a user's iphone notifications using Amazon Echo?

Tags: ios, node.js, echo, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to build an alexa skill that will be able to read your iphone notifications. I've looked at a few node.js (the language we're building the skill with) options but those seem to only work on Mac computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to read iPhone notifications with an Alexa skill, since Alexa has no way to talk to an iPhone. The code you write for an Alexa skill is run either on AWS Lambda (in the cloud) or in a web app you write, not on a personal Mac or iPhone.